# Why can't I mount a RAID array?

Tags: debian, mount, raid, software-raid

I have a RAID array which seem, if I understand it correctly, to be working correctly:

```
# cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid1] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10] 
md127 : active raid1 sdc1[0] sdb1[2]
      1951427392 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]
      
unused devices: <none>
```

and:

```
# mdadm -D /dev/md127
/dev/md127:
           Version : 1.2
     Creation Time : Mon Jun 30 11:34:10 2014
        Raid Level : raid1
        Array Size : 1951427392 (1861.03 GiB 1998.26 GB)
     Used Dev Size : 1951427392 (1861.03 GiB 1998.26 GB)
      Raid Devices : 2
     Total Devices : 2
       Persistence : Superblock is persistent

       Update Time : Mon Sep 13 22:35:53 2021
             State : clean 
    Active Devices : 2
   Working Devices : 2
    Failed Devices : 0
     Spare Devices : 0

Consistency Policy : resync

              Name : vm1:0  (local to host vm1)
              UUID : 0db83822:c53b4237:6ad8219b:40bc9f1c
            Events : 119625

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0       8       33        0      active sync   /dev/sdc1
       2       8       17        1      active sync   /dev/sdb1
```

However, if I do:

```
# mount /dev/md127 /data/
```

then nothing happens, and the following message is shown in syslog:

```
systemd[1]: media-storage.mount: Unit is bound to inactive unit dev-md0.device. Stopping, too.
systemd[1]: Unmounting /data...
systemd[1]: media-storage.mount: Succeeded.
systemd[1]: Unmounted /data.
```

When I run `fdisk`, it shows the following output:

```
# fdisk -l
Disk /dev/sda: 223.57 GiB, 240057409536 bytes, 468862128 sectors
Disk model: SanDisk SDSSDXPS
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x98ee38b9

Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *         2048 466862079 466860032 222.6G 83 Linux
/dev/sda2       466864126 468860927   1996802   975M  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       466864128 468860927   1996800   975M 82 Linux swap / Solaris


Disk /dev/sdb: 1.82 TiB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
Disk model: ST2000DM001-1ER1
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xe4628c28

Device     Boot      Start        End    Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1             2048 3903119359 3903117312  1.8T fd Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sdb2       3903119360 3907024895    3905536  1.9G 82 Linux swap / Solaris


Disk /dev/sdc: 1.82 TiB, 2000397852160 bytes, 3907027055 sectors
Disk model: ST2000VX000-1CU1
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x000ccc21

Device     Boot      Start        End    Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdc1             2048 3903119359 3903117312  1.8T fd Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sdc2       3903119360 3907024895    3905536  1.9G 82 Linux swap / Solaris


Disk /dev/md127: 1.82 TiB, 1998261649408 bytes, 3902854784 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
```

It seems that `/dev/md127` is already formatted:

```
# mkfs /dev/md127
mke2fs 1.46.2 (28-Feb-2021)
/dev/md127 contains a ext4 file system
    last mounted on /data on Mon Sep 13 22:35:53 2021
Proceed anyway? (y,N)
```

1. What is happening here?
2. Why is there is a mention in the first line in syslog of a `md0` device, instead of `md127`?
3. How do I fix it?

Comment: What is the output of `fdisk -l`? Did you format (or attempt to format) the `/dev/md127` device with a filesystem (i.e. `mkfs /dev/md127`)?

Comment: @John: I edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That "Unit is bound to inactive unit dev-md0.device." message, especially with it refering to a different device name, makes me think systemd has somehow become screwed up. A search confirmed my thought, and offered a solution that basically was:

1. Recreate the mountpoint
2. Run `systemctl daemon-reload`

(The page I found when searching was: https://databaseinaction.com/article/systemd-unit-awscsrdb-mount-is-bound-to-inactive-unit-dev-nvme8n1-device-stopping-too/ )

I can't see what step 1 would change, but I won't claim to understand systemd.

Comment: Indeed, doing `systemctl daemon-reload` solved the problem (no need to remove and recreate the directory), and I can now mount the RAID array. I'll leave the question for a few days in case someone comes with an explanation of the thing. If no explanation is provided, I shall accept your answer.